# Select * but group by a certain column, only for a certain column

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my table structure

Company table

```
|id|name|company_id
```

Images table

```
|id|file|type|company_id
```

Now, I am trying to group by type from images, it can have 2 types (logo|banner), but if I use `group by type` that will do it for all the rows, not just where the id = company id

My query so far:

```
SELECT * FROM companies c
    LEFT JOIN images i
        ON i.comp_id = c.id
```

As mentioned above if I do the following

```
SELECT * FROM companies c
    LEFT JOIN images i
        ON i.comp_id = c.id 
group by type
```

It will group ALL rows (as you would expect), so how can I group by type and only where the company_id (from images) is the same?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  `SELECT *` with `GROUP BY` is simply broken and shows a lack of understanding of how SQL should work.  What are you trying to do?  Explain in English or with correct queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by multiple fields:

```
GROUP BY `type`, `company_id`
```

Sidenote: using GROUP BY without any aggregate functions is usually a mistake, and most RDBMS will not let you GROUP BY without specifying all non-aggregated fields; but am I correct assuming you are working your way towards that?

Comment: I'm downvoting the first part of the answer and upvoting the second part

Comment: @Strawberry I'd have fleshed out the first part more, but I felt like explaining the basic function of GROUP BY to that degree would border on condescending.